# MySQL select multiple fields using vertical data

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database where the table was set up to store the data in a vertical fashion:

```
Userid -- Field -- Data
186       30       New York
186       31       Phone
186       32       Delta

187       30       Los Angeles
187       31       Website
187       32       US Air
```

I am able to select columns if they are already horizontal but want to be able to organize the output so it looks like this:

```
Userid -- Data30   --   Data31 -- Data32
186       New York      Phone     Delta
187       Los Angeles   Website   US Air
```

How do I say "Select DATA30 to show for this column but only if FIELD equals 30"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic pivot table. Using `MAX()` aggregates and `GROUP BY` with `CASE`, you can convert the rows to columns.  This will only work properly if the values for `Field` are limited and well-defined.

The purpose of the `MAX` aggregate is only to eliminate `NULL` for each value, so instead of 3 rows per `Userid` with only one of the values non-null, they are collapsed into a single row.

```
SELECT
  Userid,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Field = 30 THEN Data ELSE NULL END) AS Data30,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Field = 31 THEN Data ELSE NULL END) AS Data31,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Field = 32 THEN Data ELSE NULL END) AS Data32
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY Userid
```

Comment: Your syntax ran just fine... but only for a single person in the data. I have about 100 records and this only showed the first one on the list. Anything additional I need to do?

Comment: @Mr_Thomas You didn't forget the `GROUP BY`, did you? That would cause it to return only one row.

Comment: Let me put it this way: when I run your syntax by itself, it works. I'm trying to include this in a much larger query but I'll take what I can get. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select Userid, 
if(Field=30,Data,null),
if(Field=31,Data,null),
if(Field=32,Data,null) 
from table1
group by Userid;
```

Comment: In the 3 fields, they all showed as NULL. Not sure what happened.